# Array Strange Postfix Evaluation

Tags: java

I have created an array of primitives and if i executes **arr[index]++**, then strange enough the content of my array is getting modified. Could someone explain why the content of array is getting modified. I am also pasting the sample code which illustrates the problem :

```
ExpectedOutput iArr[0] = 0 , tmpArr = [1, 2, 3]

ActualOutput iArr[0] = 1 , tmpArr = [1, 5, 3]
```

Sample Class:

```
class ArrayTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int i = 1;
        int[] iArr = { 0 };

        incr(iArr);

        System.out.println("iArr[0] = " + iArr[0]);

        int[] tmpArr = {1, 2, 3};

        for (int j = 0; j < tmpArr.length; j++) {
            tmpArr[i]++;
        }


        System.out.println("tmpArr = " + Arrays.toString(tmpArr));

    }

    public static void incr(int[] n) {            
        n[0]++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What would you expect it to do instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays are effectively collections of variables - so an array access expression refers to a variable, as per [section 15.13 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13):

> An array access expression refers to a variable that is a component of an array.
>
> ...
>
> The result of an array access expression is a variable of type T, namely the variable within the array selected by the value of the index expression.

As it's a variable, it can be incremented as normal - or used in a compound assignment expression, e.g.

```
x[i] += 10;
```

In the underlying byte code, this translates into load locally / modify / store instructions.

Answer (score 3):

```
for (int j = 0; j < tmpArr.length; j++) {
        tmpArr[i]++;
}
```

You're incrementing the `i` index (`1`) 3 times.  You're not touching index `0` or index `2`.

So your original array is `{1, 2, 3}` and your final array is `{1, 5, 3}`, (hint: 2+3 = 5).

You directly increment `iArr[0]` with the `incr` method, so I'm not sure why you expect it to print `0` rather than `1`.  And I don't understand why you expect `tmpArr` to be `{1,2,3}`.  I can see how you expect `tmpArr` to be `{2, 3, 4}`, and if that's the case, then:

```
for (int j = 0; j < tmpArr.length; j++) {
        tmpArr[j]++;
}
```

will fix that.

Comment: Make sense , could you plz also mention why iArr[0] print 1

Comment: Edited my answer.  Maybe you need to elaborate on why you expect `iArr[0]` to print anything other than `1`.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the loop in which you actually increment the values:

```
for (int j = 0; j < tmpArr.length; j++) {
     tmpArr[i]++;
}
```

You constantly increase tmpArr[i] which is tmpArr[1], rather than tmpArr[j], thus the second value is incremented three times, and the others are not incremented at all.

Answer (score 1):

`tmpArr[i]++` is equal to `tmpArr[i] += 1` - increment by one the value stored in tmpArr[i]